# Kubernetes dashboard not working, “already exists” and “could not find the requested resource (get services heapster)”

Tags: dashboard

I am new to Kubernetes

The goal is to get Kubernetes cluster dashboard working

When I do `kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml --validate=false` as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/)

I get:

```
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml": secrets "kubernetes-dashboard-certs" already exists
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml": serviceaccounts "kubernetes-dashboard" already exists
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml": roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kubernetes-dashboard-minimal" already exists
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml": rolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kubernetes-dashboard-minimal" already exists
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml": deployments.extensions "kubernetes-dashboard" already exists
Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml": services "kubernetes-dashboard" already exists
```

When I run `kubectl get services --namespace kube-system`, I get:

```
NAME                   CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kube-dns               10.233.0.3      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   10d
kubernetes-dashboard   10.233.28.132   <none>        80/TCP          9d
```

When I try to reach the dashboard kubernetes cluster, I get `Connection refused`

`kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system kubernetes-dashboard-4167803980-1dz53` output:

```
2017/09/27 10:54:11 Using in-cluster config to connect to apiserver
2017/09/27 10:54:11 Using service account token for csrf signing
2017/09/27 10:54:11 No request provided. Skipping authorization
2017/09/27 10:54:11 Starting overwatch
2017/09/27 10:54:11 Successful initial request to the apiserver, version: v1.7.3+coreos.0
2017/09/27 10:54:11 New synchronizer has been registered: kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder-kube-system. Starting
2017/09/27 10:54:11 Starting secret synchronizer for kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder in namespace kube-system
2017/09/27 10:54:11 Initializing secret synchronizer synchronously using secret kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder from namespace kube-system
2017/09/27 10:54:11 Initializing JWE encryption key from synchronized object
2017/09/27 10:54:11 Creating in-cluster Heapster client
2017/09/27 10:54:11 Serving securely on HTTPS port: 8443
2017/09/27 10:54:11 Metric client health check failed: the server could not find the requested resource (get services heapster). Retrying in 30 seconds.
```

How can I get the dashboard working? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5):

First delete everything:

```
kubectl delete -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

Then recreate the dashboard:

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

Start a proxy:

```
kubectl proxy
```

Then open it:

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

You can also use you k8s api address instead of localhost.
Note that in some new dashboard versions short address with `ui` for example: `k8s.api.example.com/ui` is no longer working and you need to use the long ugly one explicitly.